# Devtools: Filter (blocked-other) status in network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome's devtools, in the network tab there are occasionally rows with a status of `(blocked-other)`. Most likely caused by my ad-blocker.

How does one filter those?

(More specifically I want to filter them out. `-status-code:(blocked-other)` does not work. No, I'm not turning the ad-blocker off. No, `status-code:200` is not enough, I want to have 300 and other responses as well.)

Comment: `-status-code:0` seems to do the job.

Comment: It does seem to, yes. Thanks. Could probably put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`-status-code:0` will filter this as commented [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755132/devtools-filter-blocked-other-status-in-network-tab#comment103798121_58755132) by [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom).

Comment: Note that on my system this does filter uBlockOrigin blocked content (which are lines showing in red and having `(blocked-other)`), but not Privacy Badger blocked content (which are lines showing in grey and having `(blocked-other)`). Apparently it depends on the kind of filtering differs between these two extensions.